# Не работает pip python в командной строке

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Не работает pip в python. Что делать? Пишу в командной строке -
D:\python3>pip install pyinstaller

И выдает

```
"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Пытался через папку python3\tools\scripts, все равно не находит

Answer (score 4):

Необходимо добавить папку, где у Вас хранится `pip.exe` в системную переменную `PATH`. обратите внимание. Речь не о `pip.py`, а именно о `pip.exe`!

Делается это так: идёте в Компьютер -> Свойства -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Переменные среды. Там находите `Path` и нажимаете изменить. Ставите в конце списка `;` и дописываете путь к папке, в которой у Вас лежит `pip.exe`.

Comment: В том дело что я не могу найти pip.exe

Comment: @K0T0V Даже виндовым поиском по всему диску не ищется?

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!Я уж думал ничего не получится!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй переустановить python. Когда будешь заново устанавливать: нажми "Custom installation" и там выбери "pip".
Лично мне такое помогло, но если у тебя несколько версих python, то советую удалить все и потом переустановить! 
Удачи.